# Laravel breeze package overwrite existing files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

I am working on a laravel project, for authentication, I have used `passport` for API. and used `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` for web PHP. using `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` laravel not be able to authenticate the current user I have researched a lot and found a solution which is a package name `breeze` that offered by Laravel 8.

when I install `breeze` it adds many templates and overwrites a few functions and blades. can anyone know how to not overwrite existing function or adding templates while installing?.

Question is : how to install breeze package without breeze scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to install breeze without breeze scaffolding
Its possible to use passport with laravel ui, i dont understand, which problem have you before install breeze.?
You can just follow passport documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport

Comment: passport is only for API authentication right?

Comment: Yeah, of course, same as sanctum.

Comment: what package do I need to use for web.php?. in my case I don't need the scaffolding

Comment: Laravel/ui or laravel/breeze give you all necessary stuff, you can just copy controller code in their repository https://github.com/laravel/ui or https://github.com/laravel/breeze

Comment: the question i raised is to install breeze without scaffolding

Comment: A bit of a late reply, but if anyone's interested, Laravel provides back-end API setup without front-end scaffolding `php artisan breeze:install api` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-next

Comment: @l3fty this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, Please make this the answer here!